# Como armazenar os textos das tags span em um array em jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Preciso pegar o texto que está contido entre as tags `span`.

Essa é a estrutura que estou percorrendo:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9" class="questiontext">
            <p>
                <span>TEXTO A SER COPIADO 1.</span>
            </p>

            <p>
                <span>O objeto de estudo da lógica é:</span>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9" class="questiontext">
            <p>
                <span>TEXTO A SER COPIADO 2.</span>
            </p>

            <p>
                <span>É um sistema de normas, princípios e valores...</span>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

E esse é o código que estou usando para buscar mas não me retorna os valores como deveriam:

```
var quest = document.querySelectorAll('td[class^=questiontext] > p:nth-child(1)');

var valores = [];

for (var i = 0; i < quest.length; i++)
{
    valores.push
    (
        $(quest[i]).find( "span" )
    );
}


console.log(quest);


console.log(valores);
```

No que estou errando?

P.S. *Tenho que pegar os valores porque a ideia é no futuro pegar esses valores para marcar as  `spans`  com conteúdos repetidos.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás a usar `$(divs[i]).find( "span" )` mas estás a iterar sobre `quest`. Devia ser

```
$(divs[i]).find( "span" )
```

e nesse caso podias usar JavaScript nativo com `.querySelector()`

```js
var quest = document.querySelectorAll('td[class^=questiontext] > p:nth-child(1)');

var valores = [];

for (var i = 0; i < quest.length; i++) {
  valores.push(
    quest[i].querySelector("span")
  );
}

console.log(valores);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="9" class="questiontext">
        <p>
          <span>TEXTO A SER COPIADO 1.</span>
        </p>

        <p>
          <span>O objeto de estudo da lógica é:</span>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="9" class="questiontext">
        <p>
          <span>TEXTO A SER COPIADO 2.</span>
        </p>

        <p>
          <span>É um sistema de normas, princípios e valores...</span>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Opa! Tens razão! Então, eu mudei a variável a buscar para `quest` dentro do `for` e acrescentei `.text()` ao código. Logo, dentro de `valores.push( )` ficou assim: `$(quest[i]).find( "span" ).text()`.
Obrigado @Sergio!

Comment: @GabrielOliveira podias também usar assim: `quest[i].querySelector("span").textContent`

Comment: Sim, verdade! Funcionou aqui! Era o que precisava realmente. Obrigado @Sergio! ;)